# This video contains content from [xxx] :youtube solution code

Tags: php, youtube-api

I use php to build a music video portal. There, most of the videos are rendered from youtube. After I added some videos users started to shout, some videos are blocked.(This video contains content from [xxx]. It is restricted from playback on certain sites.)

What I want is, can you suggest a code solution to play those blocked videos by YouTube.

Comment: Host them yourself and deal with the legal letters that arrive? Not sure what you're looking for here...

Comment: Here I'm using youtube api. So I hope legal letters are not required.

Comment: Can you suggest a code solution for unscrambling eggs?

Comment: This is the code I use:<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/NWknY7vBlNY?version=3&feature=player_detailpage"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/NWknY7vBlNY?version=3&feature=player_detailpage" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></object>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the video's blocked, the video's blocked.  You can't show a blocked video, that's what blocked means. If you're depending on being able to then you're SOL.

You could always host the videos yourself if you can get a copy but then you're wide open to the legal ramifications of hosting them, not to mention the storage space and bandwidth you'll burn through at an extraordinary rate.